# UNIX Join command assistance?

Tags: unix, sorting, join

I have two sorted files that I want to join based on the first field:

FILE1:

```
sa01^DS0^Pri^PE^Prod^EC
sa02^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC
sa03^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC
sa04^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC
sa05^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC
sa06^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC
sa07^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC
sa^AS1^ABAP^PE^Prod^EC
sar^ERS^Enq^PE^Prod^EC
```

FILE2:

```
sa01^uz006p
sa02^ua009p
sa03^ua005p
sa04^uz002p
sa05^uz001p
sa06^uz011p
sa07^uz012p
sa^uz016p
sar^uz019p
```

My join command:

```
join -a1 -a2 -t'^' -1 1 -2 1 $FILE1 $FILE2
```

Gives me this:

```
sa01^DS0^Pri^PE^Prod^EC^uz006p
sa02^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC^uz009p
sa03^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC^uz005p
sa04^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC^uz002p
sa05^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC^uz001p
sa06^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC^uz011p
sa07^D0^App^PE^Prod^EC^uz012p
sa^uz016p
sar^ERS^Enq^PE^Prod^EC^uz019p
```

Why=(? I sorted both files.

Comment: That command works fine for me when using your 2 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files should have been sorted using this:

```
sort -t'^' -k1,1
```

This makes it sort correctly becuase ^ is the delimiter=)! I Hope this helps someone else!!!